# Google Sheets: Find minimum sum in an ordered array

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

My goal is to find the smallest sum of 1 entry per column in this array.

i.e. Though column 9 has the lowest value for all rows, only one value can be used, and same for all the other columns, and I want to know what combination will produce the smallest sum.

Is there any way of doing this in Google Sheets?

Thank you!

[image: image sample]

Comment: You can't do it with a formula. I remember there was a paper proposing a polynomial complexity approximation, but I'm almost sure finding the exact optimum is an NP-complete problem

Comment: Do you mean the smallest absolute value?  The answer to the problem as described would appear to be to take the minimum value from each column, but maybe you mean that you can only take one value from each row and each column in which case Marat may well be right?

Comment: Hi Tom, yeah, only one value from each row and column. I'm stumped!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

**Use this formula**

```
=INDEX(QUERY({A3:I},"Select "&
       TEXTJOIN(", ",1,ARRAYFORMULA("min(Col"&COLUMN(A3:I)&")"))),2)
```

[image]